# How can I improve this Ruby code that generates a random token of numbers?

Tags: ruby, random, numbers, token

I came up with this solution:

```
  def generate_tok(n)
    tok = ""
    n.times.inject(tok) do |n, t|
      tok += SecureRandom::random_number(9).to_s
    end
  end
```

And it works fine.

Just wondering if anyone see a way to improve it? Or a better solution.
Even a way to get rid of the initialisation `(tok="")` is welcome.

Comment: `SecureRandom::random_number(9)` will never generate a 9. Is that intentional?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is merely a code review.

Comment: No the 9 is to generate a number between 0 and 9.

Didn't wanna have numbers that would have taken 2 caracters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would start with something like this:

```
require 'securerandom'

def generate_token(length)
  Array.new(length) { SecureRandom::random_number(10) }.join
end
```

Comment: Seems nicer :) 
Just would use a 9 instead of 10, because n>=10 is 2 caracters instead of 1 once converted to string.

Comment: @gdurelle: `random_number(10)` will choose a random number between `0` and `<10` which means in the range `(0..9)`. If you use `random_number(9)` you will only choose numbers in the range of `(0..8)`. I know this is a bit surprising, but you can read about that here: http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.3/libdoc/securerandom/rdoc/SecureRandom.html#method-c-random_number